# In simple forEach loop, second iteration passes indexOf == 0

Tags: javascript, foreach

Why does the second iteration pass? Its index is 1, but it passes the `if` condition and writes to the console.

```
var array = [1,1];
array.forEach(function(number) {
    if (array.indexOf(number) == 0 && number == 1)
        console.log(number);
});

//console:
// 1
// 1
```

Comment: you do not check the actual index, because the second parameter of the callback is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method always returns the first index of an element since both elements are same which always returns `0`. Instead, you can get the element index as the second argument in [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method callback function.

```js
var array = [1, 1];

array.forEach(function(number, i) {
  if (i == 0 && number == 1)
    console.log(number);
});
```